# How to add AllowAnonymous when using MinimalAPIs?

Tags: c#, minimal-apis

#### How to allow anonymous access to an endpoint when using MinimalAPIs?

Assume I have the code below in the `Program.cs` file of a web app, using the Minimal API syntax:

```cs
app.MapGet("/hello", () => "world");
```

When using non-minimal syntax, we could allow anonymous access to an endpoint by decorating a controller with an `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute.

How would I perform the same when using the minimal syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use `AllowAnonymousAttribute` on Minimal API handler too as described in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#allow-unauthenticated-users-to-access-an-endpoint):

```cs
app.MapGet("/login", [AllowAnonymous] () => "This endpoint is for all roles.");
```

Or alternatively  use the [`AllowAnonymous` method from `AuthorizationEndpointConventionBuilderExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.authorizationendpointconventionbuilderextensions.allowanonymous?view=aspnetcore-6.0):

```cs
app.MapGet("/login2", () => "This endpoint also for all roles.")
   .AllowAnonymous();
```

Comment: Why does adding the [AllowAnonymous] give me "error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AllowAnonymousAttribute' could not be found"? Is there a using I need to add?

Answer (score 3):

When using the minimal syntax, you could use a chained method call as opposed to an attribute.

```cs
app.MapGet("/hello", () => "world").AllowAnonymous();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#allow-unauthenticated-users-to-access-an-endpoint